# Is doing a particular thing which is banable/not allowed on a specific platform will it be considered haram while there is nothing haram in it

Tags: halal-haram, game

Assalam-o-alaikum,
I am a gamer and we sometimes do account boosting for money it means u have to play from a new account and u have to make it reach a particular level or particular point and for it u get payed or u sell that account (considering that there is nothing haram in that game or may be some little bit harsh words only) but if doing that account boosting isn't allowed on that platform and u may get banned for it so selling those accounts will be halal or haram? While u are putting ur lot of time over it and again it(account boosting) has nothing to do with islam.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is haram to do it.
Particular rules need not be Sharia to be served. The Sharia rule that treaties have to be served (or, if the treaty is against Sharia, not to be agreed to, so that you are not bound to it and get in conflict). For example, you have to buy a ticket to travel with a train although, evidently, train tickets are not mentioned in Quran and Hadith, but still, the fare is due. Alike, the rules of the game apply if you play it, as you made a treaty with the provider of the game.

I'm not pronouncing on the topic whether or not it is halal to play this game because this was not your question.